# Update de varios registros junto com select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tenho a necessidade de fazer o UPDATE com SELECT para vários registros, hoje estou com está query:

`UPDATE banco.ordem SET valor = (SELECT (CEILING((litros * 3.67)*100)/100) AS valor_litros FROM banco.ordem WHERE ordens = 2763) WHERE ordens = 2763`

Está query atualiza somente um registro, tenho a necessidade de fazer todos os registros que colocar dentro do `IN ('2763','2768','2802', 'etc')`.

Alguém já passou por situação ou tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

William, o tópico está marcado com as tags MySQL e SQL Server. Como sabe, nem sempre uma construção SQL funciona em todos os sgbd.

Em T-SQL (SQL Server) a solução pode ser simplificada para algo como

```
-- código #1
UPDATE banco.ordem 
  set valor = round((litros * 3.67), 2, 0)
  where ordens in ('2763','2768','2802', ...);
```

Observe que a função round() foi utilizada para arredondar o resultado para duas casas decimais. O resultado fica semelhante ao uso de ceiling(x*100)/100.

**PS**: usando a função ceiling, temos:

```
-- código #2
UPDATE banco.ordem 
  set valor = ceiling( (litros * 3.67) * 100) / 100)
  where ordens in ('2763','2768','2802', ...);
```

Comment: Preciso fazer o select dentro do update para cada registro diferente. Sim o round funciona também. Mais tive que usar Ceiling. Não lembro o motivo. Mais tive um resultado que não era o esperado.

Comment: No caso uso essa query em um sql server para atender somente um cliente. Marquei mysql porque alguns clientes estão com mysql e futuramente irei implementar. Sei que todas construções não dão certo em todos banco. Mais são parecidas. E somente preciso adaptar.

Comment: Willian, o SELECT interno não é necessário se o que necessita é somente calcular o conteúdo da coluna "valor" a partir da coluna "litros", tendo definido na cláusula WHERE para quais linhas essa ação deve ser executada. 
Com relação ao uso de Ceiling(), talvez tenha optado por ele, no lugar de round(), para que o valor seja sempre arredondado para cima.

Comment: `UPDATE banco.ordem 
  set valor = round((litros * 3.67), 2, 0)
  where ordens in ('2763','2768','2802', ...);` Ele vai buscar o valor da colula e multiplicar e atualizar?

Comment: Tive que adaptar, mais realmente deu certo e a sua resposta e a mais correta para a situação.

Comment: Obrigado. Valeu

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas vamos lá.

O seu subselect não pode conter o `IN` , você terá que colocar um alias na tabela que quer dar update e usar esse alias para acessar o valor da linha atual do update no seu subselect.
O seu `IN` deverá existir apenas no where do update.

```
UPDATE banco.ordem AS ordem1
SET valor = (SELECT (CEILING((litros * 3.67)*100)/100) AS valor_litros FROM banco.ordem WHERE ordens = ordem1.ordens) 
WHERE ordens in ('2763','2768','2802', 'etc')
```

Talvez seja necessário você adaptar alguma coisa, pois não ficou claro pra mim aonde está a coluna "ordens".

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: A coluna ordem não existe. Banco.ordem é o banco e a tabela. No caso a linha tá sendo selecionada pela coluna ordens que no caso é como se fosse o id.

Comment: Entendi. Ordens e o sequencial. Está dentro da tabela ordem. Mais só estou trabalhando de uma tabela.

Comment: Deu certo, so tive que alterar `banco.ordem ordem1` para `banco.ordem AS ordem1` e `WHERE ordens = ordem1.ordem` para `WHERE ordens = ordem1.ordens`. Pedi a edição, mais não sei se vai aprovar. qualquer coisa edite. Muito obrigado irmão.